# Null Pointer Exception in array passed class

Tags: arrays, class, exception, null

So I have a project that requires a generic class that extends Number and also finds the largest and smallest value in the array, the average of all the values, and the size of the array.  This seems easy enough to implement, but I have a problem before even putting the generic part of this in place, I get a runtime error of Null Pointer Exception at x.length, regardless of which method I call, always in the same place.

```
 import java.util.Comparator;

public class test
{
   public int x[];

   public test(int x[])
   {

   }

   public void setx(int newx[])
   {
   x = newx;
   }

   public int[] getx()
   {
   return x;
   }



public int findSmallest()
{
  int i = 0;
  int temp = x[i];

  while (i < x.length)
  {
      i++;
      if(x[i] < temp)
      {
      temp = x[i];      
      }
      else
      {

      }

   }

   return temp;

   }



public int findLargest()
{
  int i = 0;
  int temp = x[i];


  while (i < x.length)
  {
      i++;
      if(x[i] > temp)
      {
         temp = x[i];
      }
      else
      {

      }

   }

   return temp;

   }

public double findMean()
{
  int i = 0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  double avg = 0.0;

  while (i < x.length)
  {
      sum += x[i];
      i++;
  }

  avg = sum / x.length;
  return avg;
}

public int findTotal()
{

  int i = x.length;

  return i;

}

public static void main (String args[])
{

int[] ia = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

test intTest = new test(ia);

System.out.println(intTest.findTotal());

}


}



Any help on how to fix this would be amazing.
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot use the setx method in the constructor. You're passing the integer array to constructor but not actually initializing the integer array inside the class. You can do this by calling the setx method in your constructor and passing the integer array x to setx method.
Hope this helps.